# Validar registros duplicados al subir CSV

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

Lo que necesito es poder subir un archivo .CSV, y si en la bd ya existe un registro con un numero de PLANILLA y PROCESO duplicado que me salte un script que diga que ya existe un registro con ese numero de planilla y proceso. hasta ahora el codigo que tengo es este:

```
extract($_POST);
if ($action == "upload") {
$archivo = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$row = 1 - 1; 
$fp = fopen ($archivo,"r");

$PLANILLA = $_POST['PLANILLA'];
$PROCESO = $_POST['PROCESO'];

mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
$query_valida_planilla = "SELECT PLANILLA, PROCESO FROM acta_entrega_huawei 
WHERE PLANILLA = '$PLANILLA' AND PROCESO = '$PROCESO'";
$valida_planilla = mysql_query($query_valida_planilla, $conexion) or 
die(mysql_error());
$row_valida_planilla = mysql_fetch_assoc($valida_planilla);
if(mysql_num_rows($valida_planilla)>0){
echo '<script>alert("Ya existe un numero de planilla y proceso duplicado en 
la base de datos, Por favor revise el archivo");</script>';

}else{
while ($data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ";")){ 
  $num = count ($data); 
  print ""; 
  $row++; 

  $insertar="INSERT INTO acta_entrega_huawei (IDE, PLANILLA, N_PEDIDO, 
  PROCESO, FECHA_E_FAC, HORA, FECHA_E_CON, FECHA_OPE, OBSERVACIONES) VALUES 
  ('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]', '$data[4]', '$data[5]', 
  '$data[6]', '$data[7]', '$data[8]')"; 
  mysql_query($insertar);
  }   
  fclose ($fp); 

  echo "<td><center><font face=\"arial\" color=\"green\"><b>Registros 
  Insertados ".$row."</b></font></center></td>";
     }
  }
```

Cuando subo el archivo me dice que se han insertado N registros, así estén duplicados, pero en la bd no se inserta nada, pero tampoco me muestra la alerta de registros duplicados. Ya he verificado varios post pero no encuentro la solucion. Espero me puedan ayudar y de antemano Gracias.

Comment: si no te hace el volcado del csv es por que el csv debe tener algun error.

Comment: yo tengo algo que me permite subir csv pero lo tengo con PDO es mucho mas flexible

Comment: El archivo CSV me sube bien, sin error, lo que necesito tal cual como dice el titulo es que no se suban registros duplicados, quiero validar que antes de insertar me diga si hay registros duplicados en la bd.

Comment: quieres que te diga que hay registros duplicado; luego que suba los que no están suplicados? cual registro exactamente no quieres que se duplique de todos los que vas a subir alguna columna en especial???

Comment: ten en cuenta que si no te esta insertando nada debe existir algún error en el csv que no permite subir la info, puede ser por los duplicados, necesito me respondas la anterior pregunta para poder ayudarte con el código.

Comment: Quiero que me diga antes de insertar si ya hay registros en la bd iguales que los del CSV, eso es lo que pretendo con la sentencia SELECT en el codigo que puse, que obviamente no me sirve

Comment: bueno es algo muy amplio ya que tendrias que hacer un select previo y ver si hay un resultado, si el resultado es true simplemente no insertas nada y mandas el error por pantalla de lo contrario sigues insertando datos.

Comment: pero si de las 9 columnas al menos una no es igual ... tratara de insertar el registro, el problema es que si tienes columnas únicas dará un error y romperá la inserción y por ende hará el rollback de insertado de CSV y no te saldrá nada. ahora quiero que me digas si hay columnas únicas.

Comment: es eso o si existe uno solo repetido que no inserte ninguno, no me importa, solo quiero que valide por lo menos uno

Comment: no hay columnas unicas

Comment: no es tan sensillo a decir que valide uno, en realidad necesito que especifiques que parametros quieres que valide de lo contrario es una pregunta muy abierta y la reportare como tal. y no podre darte una respuesta acertada a lo que buscas

Comment: Solo quiero que si hay uno repetido que no me ingrese ninguno, eso es lo que quiero

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61941/discussion-between-francisco-nunez-and-andersson-viveros-martinez).

Comment: Ante todo, la extensión `mysql_query` está obsoleta. Si te pasas a PDO ([aquí tienes una clase ya hecha](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO), la puedes adaptar si quieres), sería muy fácil. **1.** Haces un `SELECT ... ` con un `WHERE` que use las columnas que quieres verificar. **2.** Ir creando una sentencia `INSERT INTO ...` dinámica con `?`. **3.** Si el `SELECT` de (1)  devuelve datos, no agregas nada a tu sentencia INSERT dinámica, si no devuelve datos, agregas los valores a tu INSERT dinámico y vas construyendo un array con los valores a insertar. **4.** Al final ejecutas el INSERT.